# how to prevent objects from being in the same place

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a program that uses timers to randomly define the location of 3 picturebox's. How do I make timers never set the same location for two different pictureboxes?

Code:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    PictureBox1.Left = rnd.Next(0, 451)
    PictureBox1.Top = rnd.Next(0, 205)
End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    PictureBox2.Left = rnd.Next(0, 451)
    PictureBox2.Top = rnd.Next(0, 205)
End Sub
```

Comment: Save generated locations in a variable and check before updating location of picture box

Comment: yes, but the picture boxes have a size of 32x, 64x and 128x. Even if I check before updating the locations, they can still partially overlap, like one being generated at 0; 10 and the other at 4; 15

Comment: Then you probably can rephrase the question and check that pictures are not overlapped before assigning new location to the picture boxes.

Comment: Basic collision mechanic, but applied to your controls.